# Movieclip not moving on its own

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I have a game. (Feel to download it [here](http://ge.tt/2Jr8sl91/v/0?c))

In my game, you may notice that the man doesn't move on its own. You have to click the screen once to get the man to move left and right with the arrow keys.

My Main.as:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.utils.getTimer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.engine.TextBaseline;

public dynamic class Main extends MovieClip
{
    // classes
    private var _physics:Physics;
    private var _timer:Timer;
    var interval_timer:TextField = new TextField();
    private var startTime:int;
    private var diff:int;
    private var _timer2:Timer
    private var _stage:MovieClip = container;
    private var _frame:int;
    private var fade:Number = 1.0;
    private var fadeAmount:Number = 0.01;
    private var _timer3:Timer = new Timer(25);
    private var retval:Boolean = false;
    var survive:TextField = new TextField();
    var survivedTime:Number;
    var isRight:Boolean=false
    var isLeft:Boolean=false
    var isUp:Boolean=false
    var isDown:Boolean=false
    var pause:TextField = new TextField();
    var pausedes:TextField = new TextField();


    public function Main()
    {
        _physics = new Physics(container);
        _physics.enable();
        _timer = new Timer(500);
        _timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerFunction);
        _timer.start();
        start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler);
        credits.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler2);
    }


        // the event listeners
        private function update(e:Event):void
        {
            var currentTime:int = getTimer();
            var _ballArray:Array = _physics._ballArray;
            var tempBall1:Ball;
            var i:int;  
            //check if we hit top
            if (((man.x - man.width / 2) <= _physics._minX))
            {
                man.x += 7;
            }
            else if (((man.x + man.width / 2) >= _physics._maxX))
            {

                man.x -= 7;
            }

            for (i = 0; i < _ballArray.length; i++)
            {
            // save a reference to ball
                tempBall1 = _ballArray[i] as Ball;

                if(_physics.hitTestCircle(tempBall1, man))
                    {   

                        man.gotoAndStop(2);
                        retval = true;
                        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyEvent);
                        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, upKey);
                        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, downKey);
                        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, move);
                    }
                if(retval)
                {
                    _physics.disable();
                    _timer2.stop();
                    survivedTime = diff;
                    _timer3.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, darken);
                    _timer3.start();
                    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

                    _physics._ballArray = [];
                    //trace("you died!");
                    retval = false;

                }
            }


                diff = currentTime*0.001 - startTime*0.001;
                interval_timer.text = String(diff);

        }

        private function darken(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            fade-= fadeAmount;
            if(fade < 0.0)
            {
                    fade = 0.0;
                    _timer3.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, darken);
                    _timer3.stop();
                    endGame();                      
            }
        container.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(fade, fade, fade, 1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        }
        private function downKey(event:KeyboardEvent)
        {
             if(event.keyCode==39)
             {
                isRight=true;
             }
             if(event.keyCode==37)
             {
                isLeft=true;
             }
             if(event.keyCode==38)
             {
             isUp=true
             }
             if(event.keyCode==40)
             {
             isDown=true
             }
        }
        private function upKey(event:KeyboardEvent){
             if(event.keyCode==39){
             isRight=false}
             if(event.keyCode==37){
             isLeft=false}
             if(event.keyCode==38){
             isUp=false}
             if(event.keyCode==40){
             isDown=false}
        }
        private function move(e:Event)
        {
             if(isRight==true)
                 {
                 man.x +=5;
                 }
             if(isLeft==true)
                 {
                 man.x -= 5;
                 }
        }
        private function frame(e:Event):void
        {
            _frame = currentFrame;
            if(_frame == 25)
            {
                startGame();
            }

        }
        private function startGame():void
        {
            _physics._ballArray = [];
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frame);
            //stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, startGame);
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _physics.remove);
            _physics.enable();              

            // enable physics simulation
            _timer2 = new Timer(500);
            _timer2.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerFunction);
            _timer2.start();
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);


            interval_timer.y = 18;
            interval_timer.x = 500;
            addChild(interval_timer);
            startTime = getTimer();



        }

        private function endGame()
        {
            var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            myFormat.size = 23;
            survive.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
            gotoAndStop(26);
            survive.x = 179.45;
            survive.y = 177.90;
            survive.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
            survive.text = String(survivedTime + " secs");
            addChild(survive);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _physics.remove);
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyEvent);
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, upKey);
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, downKey);
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, move);
            mainmenu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler5);
            retry.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler6);
            _physics._ballArray = [];
        }

        private function onKeyEvent(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if (stage.frameRate == 20)
            {
                if (e.keyCode == 80)
                {
                    stage.frameRate = 8;
                    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
                    pauseGame();

                }
            }
            else if (stage.frameRate == 8)
            {
                if (e.keyCode == 80)
                {
                    stage.frameRate = 20;
                    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);                      
                    unpause();
                }
            }
        }

        private function pauseGame():void
        {
            _physics.disable();
            _timer2.stop();
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyEvent);
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, upKey);
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, downKey);
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, move);
            var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            var myFormat2:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            myFormat.size = 30;
            myFormat2.size = 15;
            pause.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
            pausedes.defaultTextFormat = myFormat2;
            pause.x = 239.95;
            pause.y = 165.90;
            pause.textColor = 0x000000;
            pausedes.x = 221.8;
            pausedes.y = 205.45;
            pausedes.width = 130.2;
            pausedes.textColor = 0x000000;
            pause.text = String("Paused");
            pausedes.text = String("Press P to Unpause");
            addChild(pause);
            addChild(pausedes);

        }
        private function unpause():void
        {

            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyEvent);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, upKey);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, downKey);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, move);
            _physics.enable();
            _timer2.start();
            removeChild(pause);
            removeChild(pausedes);

        }
        public function timerFunction(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            _physics.createBalls(1);                
        }
        //start button
        private function buttonClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            gotoAndStop(3);
            ok.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler4);
            _physics.disable();
            _timer.stop();
            _timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerFunction);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _physics.remove);
            _physics._ballArray = [];
        }
        //credits button
        private function buttonClickHandler2(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            gotoAndStop(2);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _physics.remove);
            _physics.disable();
            _timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerFunction);
            _timer.stop();
            back.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler3);
        _physics._ballArray = [];

        }
        //back button
        private function buttonClickHandler3(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            gotoAndStop(1);
            _physics.enable();
            _timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerFunction);
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _physics.remove);
            _timer.start();
            start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler);
            credits.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler2);
            _physics._ballArray = [];

        }
        //ok button
        private function buttonClickHandler4(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, upKey);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, downKey);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, move);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyEvent);
            gotoAndPlay(4);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frame);
            _physics._ballArray = [];

            //stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, startGame);

        }
        //main menu button
        private function buttonClickHandler5(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            gotoAndStop(1);
            container.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0); 
            removeChild(survive);   
            removeChild(interval_timer);    
            _physics.enable();
            _timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerFunction);
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _physics.remove);
            _timer.start();
            start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler);
            credits.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler2);
            _physics._ballArray = [];
            fade = 1.0;
            fadeAmount = 0.01;
        }
        //retry button
        private function buttonClickHandler6(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            container.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0); 
            removeChild(survive);   
            removeChild(interval_timer);    
            gotoAndPlay(4);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frame);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, upKey);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, downKey);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, move);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyEvent);
            _physics._ballArray = [];
            fade = 1.0;
            fadeAmount = 0.01;
            man.x = 286.65;
            man.y = 391.85;
            man.gotoAndStop(1);

        }


}
```

}

This is the file I use to make the man move. Where is the code do I change to make the game work so the man moves the after "Go!", and you don't have to click the screen.

Another question I have is: When you press "P", you can pause the game. However, you may notice after unpausing the game by pressing "P" again, the timer is off by the number of seconds you were paused. This code also is the code for the timer. What do I change in the code to make the timer run correctly, meaning that after unpausing the game, it doesn't skip the number of the seconds you were paused, instead it continues from where it left off.

Comment: Not enough code. Where does it display "Go!"? Also you don't properly clear the variables for moving, I died while moving leftwards, and all the subsequent retries made the man instantly move left without ability to cancel moving.

Comment: About making timer work to exclude paused time - don't use `getTimer()` for this, instead measure frames passed in the same var `currentTime`, and if paused, don't increment the var.

Comment: It looks to me like "update" is where you move the man.  That's called from startGame, which is only called from buttonClickHandler4 and buttonClickHandler6 (where the KeyboardEvent's are bound also).  So I wouldn't expect the man to move until one of those click handlers is called.  Maybe call startGame and bind the key Events in your constructer?

Comment: If you want to track the time you are paused, you can use the [Date Class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html) to track the time you're paused.

Comment: @dhc I want the man to move automatically only after the "ok" button is pressed. Putting it in the constructor would make him move all of the time correct?

Comment: @Vesper, I see that bug also. Thank-you for notifying me, I will try to fix that.

Comment: Then don't call startGame, but you should still add your KeyboardEvent handlers in the constructor rather than waiting for the buttonClickHander's.  This should make the key events available at the start.

Comment: @dhc, another thing is that the man movieclip only comes up after the instructions page frame, therefore putting the keyEvents in the constructor is useless.

Comment: if I used addEventListener instead of stage.addEventListener, would it work?

Comment: Then the KeyboardEvent handlers should be added in the code that dismisses the instructions page.

Comment: that's the ok button handler, or buttonClickHandler6.

Comment: @dhc I meant buttonClickHandler4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** I figured out the problem using this link: http://www.trainingtutorials101.com/2010/10/keyboard-events-wont-work-unless-user.html

I had to use the command `stage.focus = this` to focus the stage on my movieclip man, so that way it could listen for keyboard events without my mouse clicking the screen.

And to remove the yellow rectangle around the man I used the command `stage.stageFocusRect = false`.

Thanks to @dhc and @Vesper for all of their help.

Answer (score 0):

This is getting too long a comment thread for this question.  After you call buttonClickHandler4, your keyboard events should be functioning.

Set debug points, or trace statements, to see if buttonClickHandler4 is being called.  Add the same to make sure downKey and move are being called.  This should narrow down the problem.

Comment: Button click handler 4 is being called, as well as downKey and move, but the problem is that you have to click the screen at least once to get the guy to move.

Comment: Why is this happening?